# How to fill a input() function with variable

Tags: python, function, input

Suppose I have the following function that asks for 2 numbers and adds them.

```
def sum():
  a = int(input('Enter the first number: '))
  b = int(input('Enter the second number: '))
  return a + b
```

Also I have two variables:

```
first_number = 2
second_number = 4
```

Considering that I can't copy paste the values of variable or change the function and the variables I want to fill in the values of these variables into the `sum` function. So, I was trying to do this by creating a function like `input_values` that could take the function and the variables as arguments and return the output of the function entered in it as an argument after imputing the variable values in it. I am working in a **jupyter notebook** and not able to understand how to build this function. Or is it possible even. Please help. The resultant function should be defined something like following:

```
def input_values(func,var1, var2):
    #The computation should be held here.
```

It should be called like this:

```
input_values(func=sum(), var1=first_number,var2=second_number)
```

Again specifying, the **`input_values`** should follow the following algo.

1. Initiate the function given to it(in this case it is the `sum` function)
2. When the `sum` function ask to enter the first value from user, fill the value of `var1` in it and somehow proceed.
3. Again, when it asks to enter the other number, enter the value of `var2` in it and proceed.
4. When the given function(`sum`) is executed, return its value.

Comment: You might want to mock `input`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46222661/476

Comment: It is possible, but quite difficult and a really good example why getting user input inside a function can be a bad idea.

Comment: Yes, just that. Your function should do one thing - here, sum numbers - and not manage the input.

Comment: I really want to help you, can you please clarify your question, or provide pseudo code to depict the desired result?

Comment: hey @JosephJulian , I want the function `input values` to take the `sum` function and put the `first_number` and `second_number` into it  and return the result of sum function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like : [Reference](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-use-python-pexpect-to-automate-linux-commands/)

Installation:

```
pip install pexpect
```

Then simply try this snippet

```
import pexpect
first_number = 2
second_number = 4
child = pexpect.spawn('your_script.py')
child.expect('Enter the first number:.*')
child.sendline(first_number)
child.expect('Enter the second number:.*')
child.sendline(second_number)
```

Make sure you call the function in your source main code

```
first_number = 2
second_number = 4
def sum():
  a = int(input('Enter the first number: '))
  b = int(input('Enter the second number: '))
  return a + b

sum()
```

Comment: Hey @Bhargav, I tried out but couldn't make it. I am new to programming and want to do the task on jupyter notebook, can you please tell what should I put on `your_script.py` or elaborate your answer a bit, I shall be highly grateful to you.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize if I am misunderstanding your question, but is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
def input_values():
  try:
    a = int(input('Enter the first number: '))
    b = int(input('Enter the second number: '))
  except(ValueError) as e:
    print(f'{str(e)}. Please only input integers.')
    input_values()
      
  return sum_numbers(a, b)
  
def sum_numbers(a, b):
  try:
    print(f'The sum of your two numbers is: {a + b}')
  except(ArithmeticError) as e:
    print(f'{str(e)}.')
  
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
  input_values()
```

Please note that I have included some simple error handling to prevent unwanted input. You will want to expand on this to ensure all user input is handled correctly.

Comment: It is rather unfortunate, though, that a function called `input_values` can't be used to just input values, because it always calls a function that sums the inputs. You should keep your functions independent.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille, you do realize that my `input_values` function is written uniquely for @BhaumikTripathi, right? I would not personally choose this function - this was my attempt at answering the original question based off of @BhaumikTripathi's request. I agree, functions should be independent.

Comment: Hey @JosephJulian , I have specified the problem more please see if you get it.